# Flutter how to select multiple days of the week and add to Hive

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

please support me I want to create an application that can select multiple days of the week. With added to Hive, what can I do?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Do you need help with the UI, hive or just in general on how to approach this?

Comment: can you clarify what you want exactly to save and did you tried to get the sates with the some date pickers ?